# Rendering bugs when SoftKeyboard closes

Tags: android, keyboard, rendering, overlay

I have the following problem:
I have a FrameLayout with a main Fragment, which is always shown, and some overlay "extra" fragments which are shown or not, depending on the state of the application. (This Layout is used on tablets)

Now, if the user initiates a dialog with an EditText, this causes the SoftKeyboard to appear.
The Dialog and the Keyboard(No matter which type of dialog, I tried AlertDialog and DialogFragment) overlays the other Fragments.
So far, so good.

But when the dialog is finished and the keyboard closes, my whole application is pushed a bit up and down in an animation, and then there are several rendering bug in the ActionBar and at the bottom edges of my fragments.

This happens only if the keyboard overlaid exactly one of my "extra" fragments. (If it overlays two fragments, then everything is good).

Anyone an idea how to get rid of this?
Configuring android:windowSoftInputMode does not help.

Answer (score 0):

You can adjust your keyboard in fragment using

```
getActivity().getWindow().setSoftInputMode(
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_ADJUST_PAN);
```

Comment: That does not help at all.  Configuring android:windowSoftInputMode does not help, and your code does exactly that (in java, of course). The keyboard overlays everything correctly, as I wish, but when the keyboard closes, then this bug occurs.